# Count of People who view my web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I would like to know how many people view my web page.
I am using asp.net 2.0 C#.

Please let me know, is there any way to know people count(s) who view my web page.

Comment: This is less simple than it sounds. Do you want to count the visits of search engine bots?  Do you want to count the visits of returning visitors? If not, you may want to consider using something like Google Analytics

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Google Analytics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Analytics) or [analyse the IIS logs](http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1864) on your web server.

Comment: But note that nothing counts the PEOPLE - only browser visits. No freaking way to know whether 1 or 3 people sit in front of the browser. Noone uses PEOPLE as measurement.

Comment: @TomTom Yes, you are right, Google Analytics (or Piwik or other tools) all will give just an broad number.

Comment: Of visitors, which has only a slight resemblance of people. Even returning visitors (same browser coming again) can sometiems be tricky to identify. It is as good as it gets, though.

Answer (score 1):

*Cough*  Google analytics  *Cough*

Answer (score 1):

if you don't need any extra information about visitors you can just increment your "counter" (which will be kept in a file,db or any other persistent store) inside Session_Start from Global.asax.