# Advertisment in application with regional settings in c#

Tags: c#, browser, regional-settings

In my application I have popup where ad is showing. But I want to do that in for example Germany will be showed ad in german language, in France in French language etc. I have WebBrowser component and I pass to Uri url with path of html file with ad which is placed on my serwer.

```
this.webBrowser.Url = new Uri("http://mydomain.com/ads/ad2.html");
```

In ad2.html I can do recognition of ip and based on this I can redirect to appropriate html file.
The problem is that in application I hear voice (tik) when site is reloading.

Thanks

Comment: there are in general 3 questions you are asking to different topics. It would be better to separate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

search the intwerwebs next time.

some links:

-1: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/e72b37d2-d20b-4a59-8560-24a10b17db97/

-2: [Ip address to country with database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775655/ip-address-to-country-with-database)

-3: [Count of People who view my web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765034/count-of-people-who-view-my-web-page)